# Difference Await.ready and Await.result

Tags: scala, future

I know this is quite an open ended question and I apologize.

I can see that `Await.ready` returns `Awaitable.type` while `Await.result` returns `T` but I still confuse them.

What are the difference between the two?

Is one blocking and the other one non-blocking?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

They both block until the future completes, the difference is just their return type.

The difference is useful when your `Future` throws exceptions:

```
def a = Future { Thread.sleep(2000); 100 }
def b = Future { Thread.sleep(2000); throw new NullPointerException }

Await.ready(a, Duration.Inf) // Future(Success(100))    
Await.ready(b, Duration.Inf) // Future(Failure(java.lang.NullPointerException))

Await.result(a, Duration.Inf) // 100
Await.result(b, Duration.Inf) // crash with java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `Await.ready` will not return the `Try` directly but you have to extract it from the future first via `Await.ready(a, d).value.get`.

Answer (score 16):

Both are blocking for at most the given `Duration`. However, `Await.result` tries to return the future result right away and throws an exception if the future failed while `Await.ready` returns the completed future from which the result (`Success` or `Failure`) can safely be extracted via the `value` property.

The latter is very handy when you have to deal with a timeout as well:

```
val future = Future { Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(2000)); 123 }

Try(Await.ready(future, 1.second)) match {
    case Success(f) => f.value.get match {
      case Success(res) => // handle future success 
      case Failure(e) => // handle future failure
    }
    case Failure(_) => // handle timeout
}
```

When using `Await.result`, the timeout exception and exceptions from failing futures are "mixed up".

```
Try(Await.result(future, 1.second)) match {
    case Success(res) => // we can deal with the result directly
    case Failure(e) => // but we might have to figure out if a timeout happened
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, both are blocking.

The difference is that `Await.ready` is blocking until the Future has finished (successful or failed) in given time.

The only one difference is that `ready` blocks until the `Awaitable` is ready and the `result` does yield the result type `T`.

**Postscriptum:**
In practice, if you want to perform some actions like error checking or logging you would take `Await.ready(...)` if you want to compose the result and throw an error if something goes wrong take `Await.result(...)`.

As rule of thumb - try to avoid Await.

Comment: Why do you say to avoid `Await`? What should be used instead? Thanks.

Comment: @LarsSkaug You should preferably return the actual future and process the result...

e.g. 

`future.flatMap(result => { // do something })`

Or whatever your preferred logic is to process the result

The problem with `Await` is that it will block whereas the above logic will allow the thread to continue on. I'd argue `Await` may make sense if you don't care about blocking and just want code that is easy to follow.