# System is not terminated in scala application in docker on GKE

Tags: scala, docker, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a scala application that uses Akka Streams and running as a cronjob in Google Kubernetes Engine. But the pod is still in the “Running” state (not completed). And the Java process is still running inside the container.

Here's what I do exactly:

I build the docker image with `sbt-native-packager` and `sbt docker:publish`.

When the job is done, I terminate it with regular `system.terminate` call.

```
implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("actor-system")

/* doing actual stuff */

stream.runWith(
    Sink. // whatever's here
  ).onComplete { _ ⇒
    println("finished!!!")
    system.terminate()
  }
```

I see `finished!!!` in logs, so the `system.terminate` must be called.

If I bash into the pod and run `ps aux` I still see the java process running.

```sh
demiourgos728@crawler-manual-f9tdf-mjcvn:/opt/docker$ ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
demiour+       1  0.1 17.1 2418900 296532 ?      Ssl  Oct13   4:22 /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java -cp /opt/docker/lib/crawler.crawler-2.0.0.jar
demiour+     212  0.0  0.2   5752  3656 pts/0    Ss   15:25   0:00 /bin/bash
demiour+     218  0.0  0.1   9392  3064 pts/0    R+   15:25   0:00 ps aux
```

This works when I run it locally as a standalone application, and also terminates when I run it locally with docker.

How do I make sure that the application is terminated and therefore pod's status becomes “Completed”?

Here's how the cronjob is defined:

```
# cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: crawler
spec:
  schedule: "49 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: crawler-cronjob
              image: eu.gcr.io/myawesomeproject/crawler:latest
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

**UPDATE**

I updated my code as suggested with these lines:

```scala
stream.runWith(
    Sink. // whatever's here
  ).onComplete { _ ⇒
    println("finished!!!")
    system.terminate()
    Await.ready(system.whenTerminated, 300.second)
    println("and terminated!!!")
  }
```

And this is what I see in the logs:

```
2020-10-27 09:52:19.375 CEST finished!!!
2020-10-27 09:52:19.489 CEST [ERROR] [10/27/2020 07:52:19.476] [actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka://actor-system/system/pool-master] connection pool for Pool(shared->https://some-api-url.com:443) has shut down unexpectedly
2020-10-27 09:52:19.489 CEST java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool shutdown unexpectedly
                                at akka.http.impl.engine.client.PoolInterface$Logic.postStop(PoolInterface.scala:214)
                                at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.finalizeStage(GraphInterpreter.scala:599)
                                at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.finish(GraphInterpreter.scala:324)
                                ...
2020-10-27 09:52:19.508 CEST and terminated!!!
```

But next time I run it (with updated messaging) this happens:

```scala
  system.registerOnTermination({
    println("\n\n really terminated!!! \n\n")
  })
```

[image]

This is jstack output:

```
demiourgos728@crawler-manual-7nkq9-lklv8:/opt/docker$ jstack 1
2020-10-27 11:38:15
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.265-b01 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" #158 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1150089800 nid=0xe3 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"async-channel-group-0-timeout-thread" #45 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f115c008000 nid=0x59 waiting on condition [0x00007f1143f3f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eee416a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"DestroyJavaVM" #42 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f117400b800 nid=0x2c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"async-channel-group-0-handler-executor" #41 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11581e1800 nid=0x56 waiting on condition [0x00007f1144040000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eee39c58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"cluster-5f93dae7deb88a3b7a33ab63" #40 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11748d0000 nid=0x55 waiting on condition [0x00007f1144341000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e599e360> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster$WaitQueueHandler.run(BaseCluster.java:491)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"cluster-rtt-ClusterId{value='5f93dae7deb88a3b7a33ab63', description='null'}-yatta-shard-00-02.z3l5v.gcp.mongodb.net:27017" #39 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11748bd800 nid=0x54 waiting on condition [0x00007f1144442000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:435)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor.access$1300(DefaultServerMonitor.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$RoundTripTimeRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:409)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"cluster-ClusterId{value='5f93dae7deb88a3b7a33ab63', description='null'}-yatta-shard-00-02.z3l5v.gcp.mongodb.net:27017" #38 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1174670800 nid=0x53 waiting on condition [0x00007f1144543000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eee507c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:294)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:275)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"cluster-rtt-ClusterId{value='5f93dae7deb88a3b7a33ab63', description='null'}-yatta-shard-00-01.z3l5v.gcp.mongodb.net:27017" #37 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f117465d000 nid=0x52 waiting on condition [0x00007f1144644000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:435)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor.access$1300(DefaultServerMonitor.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$RoundTripTimeRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:409)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"cluster-ClusterId{value='5f93dae7deb88a3b7a33ab63', description='null'}-yatta-shard-00-01.z3l5v.gcp.mongodb.net:27017" #36 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f117465b800 nid=0x51 waiting on condition [0x00007f1144745000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eee50b40> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:294)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:275)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"cluster-rtt-ClusterId{value='5f93dae7deb88a3b7a33ab63', description='null'}-yatta-shard-00-00.z3l5v.gcp.mongodb.net:27017" #35 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1174656000 nid=0x50 waiting on condition [0x00007f1144846000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:435)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor.access$1300(DefaultServerMonitor.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$RoundTripTimeRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:409)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"cluster-ClusterId{value='5f93dae7deb88a3b7a33ab63', description='null'}-yatta-shard-00-00.z3l5v.gcp.mongodb.net:27017" #34 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11743f6800 nid=0x4f waiting on condition [0x00007f1144947000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000eee50ec0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:294)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:275)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Thread-1" #32 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1175354800 nid=0x4d runnable [0x00007f1144b49000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c2f8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c308> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c2b0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.connection.TlsChannelStreamFactoryFactory$SelectorMonitor.lambda$start$0(TlsChannelStreamFactoryFactory.java:136)
    at com.mongodb.connection.TlsChannelStreamFactoryFactory$SelectorMonitor$$Lambda$698/375074687.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"async-channel-group-0-selector" #31 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1175350000 nid=0x4c runnable [0x00007f1144c4a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c548> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c558> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c500> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.loop(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:392)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup$$Lambda$696/548795052.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"AsyncAppender-Worker-ASYNC" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11580ad000 nid=0x3b waiting on condition [0x00007f11475fa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000ee865d38> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase$Worker.run(AsyncAppenderBase.java:289)

"Service Thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11740b6000 nid=0x33 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11740b3000 nid=0x32 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11740b1000 nid=0x31 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f117409e800 nid=0x30 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f117407d800 nid=0x2f in Object.wait() [0x00007f1178498000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    - locked <0x00000000ee59ad48> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1174079000 nid=0x2e in Object.wait() [0x00007f1178599000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000000ee59af00> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f117406f800 nid=0x2d runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11740b9000 nid=0x34 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 3679
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is related to GKE in particular, or Kubernetes in general: your `CronJob` definition looks fine and, at first glance, everything should work fine.

I assume your `Dockerfile` is correct too and defines an entry point and/or command that just starts the JVM process.

Probably your problem is that the `ActorSystem` is never actually terminated for any reason: maybe some actor could not be terminated or there is some problem while the actor system is being terminated.

To test this assumption and help debug the problem, you can register a simple [`registerOnTermination`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html#registerOnTermination(scala.Function0)) callback and await for system termination, something like:

```scala
implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("actor-system")

system.registerOnTermination {
  println("the actor system is terminated")
}

/* doing actual stuff */

stream.runWith(
    Sink. // whatever's here
  ).onComplete { _ ⇒
    println("finished!!!")
    system.terminate()
    // Use ready or result, with the amount of time you consider   
    // appropriate, and analyze the results (timeout, error, ...) provided
    // See, for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170280/difference-await-ready-and-await-result
    Await.ready(system.whenTerminated(), 100.second)
  }
```

Pay special attention if you are using third party resources like a database or some other store system for storing your crawl results. In fact, reviewing your update, and as @TomerShetah also has indicated, it is very likely the case: it seems that you can have some kind of connection leak in your code related with Mongo. Please, carefully review your code. Also, it would be great if you can further process the results of the `Await` call in order to discard a timeout as the cause of the leak.

I think it would be also of help if you can update your answer with further information related with your setup. For instance, where is Mongo? Are you deploying it also in k8s?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the update to the question proves that the actor system is actually terminated.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes Tomer, although it would be interesting to understand why this error occurs when the system is terminating. I wonder if it could be related with the await logic. In any case, the threads are reporting activity in the mongo driver, it could be a connection leak indeed.

Answer (score 1):

When investigating your JStack, it looks like the actor system is really down. As you see in your logs, there are no running threads occupied by the ActorSystem.

The threads that are currently running are the ones having the following line:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

The running threads are:

```
"Attach Listener" #158 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1150089800 nid=0xe3 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"DestroyJavaVM" #42 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f117400b800 nid=0x2c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Thread-1" #32 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1175354800 nid=0x4d runnable [0x00007f1144b49000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c2f8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c308> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c2b0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.connection.TlsChannelStreamFactoryFactory$SelectorMonitor.lambda$start$0(TlsChannelStreamFactoryFactory.java:136)
    at com.mongodb.connection.TlsChannelStreamFactoryFactory$SelectorMonitor$$Lambda$698/375074687.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"async-channel-group-0-selector" #31 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1175350000 nid=0x4c runnable [0x00007f1144c4a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c548> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c558> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000eee0c500> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.loop(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:392)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup$$Lambda$696/548795052.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Service Thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11740b6000 nid=0x33 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11740b3000 nid=0x32 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11740b1000 nid=0x31 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f117409e800 nid=0x30 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

6 out of the 8 threads, are daemon threads. According to [b_erb great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213348/2359227):

> A daemon thread is a thread that does not prevent the JVM from exiting when the program finishes but the thread is still running.

The remaining 2, are:

- [DestroyJavaVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34433567/2359227) - that is responsible for quitting the program.
- async-channel-group-0-selector - This is the one we should closely look at. This thread is locked, waiting at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.

Is it possible that you opened a connection to mongodb and forgot to close it? Can it be in that area?

The error you report to have, is actually reported in [github](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1612). It was caused due to an open http connection. This also supports the theory of open connection to mongodb. This bug was fixed in version 10.1.0 of akka-http client. So I assume that if you upgrade to latest(currently 10.2.1) this error will disappear.

Comment: Tomen, I think it could not be reason of the problem, Konstantin is actually using a version of the library greater than or equal 10.1.9: this is the version in which ```PoolInterface```, the class found in the error in the console, was included, and in that version of the library the bug is supposed to be fixed according to your answer.